# Making a universal method for different buttons

Tags: java, android

I have several buttons in my program and obviously each button redirects to some page. doing it this way seems too repetitive. What can i do to make it less repetitive?

```
public class learn_frontpageController {
    Parent root;
    Stage stage;

    public void getScene() {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void homeButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../sample/frontpage.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        getScene();
    }

    public void learnCloudsButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml_learningPage/learn_clouds.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        getScene();
    }

    public void learnWindButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml_learningPage/learn_wind.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        getScene();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically changing the String being passed in `getResource`, so make a method that requires a `String` argument for the path:

```
public void handleButton(ActionEvent actionEvent, String path) throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        getScene();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate method for the repetitive part of the code.

```
public void learnWindButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml_learningPage/learn_wind.fxml"));

        repetitivePart ();
    }


 public void repetitivePart () {
    stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    getScene();
}
```